# CSound ignores 0dbfs assignment and terminates immediately

Tags: csound

I am working through the CSound FLOSS manual and am perplexed by the results I'm getting with one particular example demonstrating the use of RMS in CSound. The example can be found on page 28 in the pdf version, or on [this page](https://floss.booktype.pro/csound/c-intensities/) under the 'RMS Measurement' heading within the html version.

```
<CsoundSynthesizer>
<CsOptions>
-odac
</CsOptions>
<CsInstruments>
;example by Martin Neukom, adapted by Joachim Heintz
sr = 44100
ksmps = 32
nchnls = 2
0dbfs = 1

giSine    ftgen     0, 0, 2^10, 10, 1 ;table with a sine wave

instr 1
a3        init      0
kamp      linseg    0, 1.5, 0.2, 1.5, 0        ;envelope for initial input
asnd      poscil    kamp, 440, giSine          ;initial input
if p4 == 1 then                                ;choose between two sines ...
 adel1     poscil    0.0523, 0.023, giSine
 adel2     poscil    0.073, 0.023, giSine,.5
else                                           ;or a random movement for the delay lines
 adel1     randi     0.05, 0.1, 2
 adel2     randi     0.08, 0.2, 2
endif
a0        delayr    1                          ;delay line of 1 second
a1        deltapi   adel1 + 0.1                ;first reading
a2        deltapi   adel2 + 0.1                ;second reading
krms      rms       a3                         ;rms measurement
          delayw    asnd + exp(-krms) * a3     ;feedback depending on rms
a3        reson     -(a1+a2), 3000, 7000, 2    ;calculate a3
aout      linen     a1/3, 1, p3, 1             ;apply fade in and fade out
          outs      aout, aout
endin
</CsInstruments>
<CsScore>
i 1 0 60 1          ;two sine movements of delay with feedback
i 1 61 . 2          ;two random movements of delay with feedback
</CsScore>
</CsoundSynthesizer>
```

When I run csound with the file as input using `csound ex5.csd` the following output follows.

```
0dBFS level = 32768.0
--Csound version 6.10 (double samples) 2018-01-27 
[commit: none]
libsndfile-1.0.28
UnifiedCSD:  ex5cp.csd
STARTING FILE
Creating options
Creating orchestra
closing tag
Creating score
rtaudio: ALSA module enabled
rtmidi: ALSA Raw MIDI module enabled

csound command: Segmentation fault
end of score.          overall amps:      0.0
       overall samples out of range:        0
0 errors in performance
```

This all happens immediately, with no sound output to be heard. I am guessing this isn't the intention of the example, and that the `0dBFS level = 32768.0` log message has something to do with the problem. I am asking here because I get the same result even when I copy paste the program from the book, so I am sort of stumped.

Any insight into what's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it has anything to do with the 0dbfs assignment. you can compare with any other .csd which works for you: you will find it always first in the output console.

i checked the example, and it works for me as expected (csound 6.14 develop).

as you use csound 6.10, my first recommendation is to update your csound.  the problem ist that you get a segmentation fault, so no way to know more about the issue without special tools.

by the way, there is a new version of the csound floss manual at https://flossmanual.csound.com/

the examples can now be played directly from the browser (for now, chrome/chromium works best).

hope this helps -
  joachim